# Postgres GROUP BY returns all rows when primary key is included

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a simple group by statement where I need to retrieve the primary key `id` of the row that has the max value of scheduled for the aggregate.

```
select id, max(scheduled) from event group by customer_id, id;
```

This returns all results with the scheduled value as the max(scheduled) for each customer.

If I don't include the id the aggregate works as expected.

```
select max(scheduled) from event group by customer_id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PK by design is unique. So you get as many groups as PK values.
You could use:

```
SELECT id, customer_id, scheduled AS max_scheduled
FROM event
WHERE (customer_id, scheduled) = (select customer_id, max(scheduled) 
                                  from event 
                                  group by customer_id);
```

Comment: Thanks, the mental fog of the morning has not quite lifted

Answer (score 2):

Another way to achieve what you want is using [DISTINCT ON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (customer_id) id, scheduled
FROM event
ORDER BY customer_id, scheduled DESC;
```